# What does 調子乗 mean?

Tags: meaning

"....バイト先でお客さんから人気な自分アピールしてくる大学生の店員が聞いてもないのに　「オレのオススメはこれっすねー」とか言ってくるのなんか**調子乗ってて**....."

I can't find any meanings so thank you if you will help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

調子に乗る is an expression meaning "to get carried away," "to get caught up in the moment," or a variety of other possible English translations.

Sometimes particles like に are omitted in casual Japanese.